# Alfresco copy with aspects / REST API

Tags: java, rest, alfresco, cmis

I am writing a custom application that interfaces with Alfresco community 4.2.  I have a custom data model integrated, and learned to my chagrin that I can't copy a document using CMIS, because custom aspects are not recognized (as in [this issue](http://forums.alfresco.com/forum/developer-discussions/alfresco-api/cmis-atompub-copy-issue-11092012-1608)).  I could do it manually, I suppose, by copying all the properties and setting the type as appropriate, but I hit upon the idea of using the built-in copy action to accomplish my task, and call this action via REST API.  It seems as if this should copy custom types properly, no?

1) Does this sound like a good approach?

2) How do I call the copy action via REST?  I can't even figure out the URL I should be using for this.  I've seen some documentation, but haven't been able to sort it out yet.

Thanks!

Comment: Alfresco supports Aspects over CMIS just fine! In CMIS 1.0 they're exposed as Policies, in 1.1 they're available directly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using 4.2.e, so, as Gagravarr says, aspects are supported in CMIS 1.0 using the OpenCMIS Extension for Alfresco. And in CMIS 1.1, which is supported in 4.2.e, as secondaryTypes (synonym for aspects).

Important to note is that in 4.2 the CMIS URLs have changed. If you want to use CMIS 1.0 AtomPub the URL is:

```
http://localhost:8080/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.0/atom
```

And if you want to use CMIS 1.1 AtomPub the URL is:

```
http://localhost:8080/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/atom
```

Given those URLs, Alfresco 4.2.e, OpenCMIS 0.10.0, and the OpenCMIS extension 0.7, the following is the outcome of running this code:

```
Document sourceDoc = (Document) cmisSession.getObjectByPath("/Someco/Whitepapers/whitepaper2.txt");
Folder targetFolder = (Folder) cmisSession.getObjectByPath("/destinationFolder");
sourceDoc.copy(targetFolder);
```

Where whitepaper2.txt is a document with multiple custom aspects and custom metadata set:

**CMIS 1.0 AtomPub, no OpenCMIS extension**: Copy succeeds without the custom aspects.

**CMIS 1.0 AtomPub, OpenCMIS extension**: Copy fails with IllegalArgumentException.

**CMIS 1.1, no OpenCMIS extension** (it isn't needed): Copy succeeds with all custom aspects and
property values intact.

So the answer is to use CMIS 1.1 support when running against 4.2.x.

Comment: I should note that when you use the OpenCMIS extension, you need to work with AlfrescoDocument and AlfrescoFolder instead of Document and Folder. Regardless, the copy will fail using CMIS 1.0 AtomPub and the OpenCMIS extension as noted, so I have created an issue against the OpenCMIS extension project http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/alfresco-opencmis-extension/issues/detail?id=10

Comment: Sure enough, I changed to the proper URL and things started working... how about that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Taken from the [Alfresco forum](https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/developer-discussions/alfresco-api/copy-folder-including-aspects-using-cmis-07302012-1018)

```
public static void copyDocument(Folder parentFolder, Document toCopyDocument) {
    Map<String, Object> documentProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>(2);

    documentProperties.put(PropertyIds.NAME, toCopyDocument.getName());

    // Retrieve aspects for this document - NEW
    Iterator<ObjectType> aspects = ((AlfrescoDocument)toCopyDocument).getAspects().iterator();
    String aspectIds = "";
    while (aspects.hasNext()) {
        aspectIds += ',';
        aspectIds += aspects.next().getId();
    }
    documentProperties.put(PropertyIds.OBJECT_TYPE_ID,
                   toCopyDocument.getBaseTypeId().value() + aspectIds);

    toCopyDocument.copy(parentFolder, documentProperties, null, null, null,
                null, null);
  }
```

So basically you're retrieving the aspects and 'resending' them.